# $C_c^\infty(\Omega)\subseteq L^p(\Omega)$ for any open $\Omega$?

Tags: lp-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$. Can we show that $$C_c^\infty(\Omega)\subseteq L^p(\Omega)\tag 1$$ for all $p\in [1,\infty]$? It's clear that $(1)$ holds if $\Omega$ has finite Lebesgue measure. And it's clear that $(1)$ holds for $p=\infty$.

Comment: Since and $f\in C^{\infty}_{\text{c}}$ is bounded, the $L^{p}$-norm is finite. If $\Omega$ is unbounded, this is still true, since the support of and $f$ is compact...

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The answer to the question may be straightforward, but that does not mean the question is bad.

Comment: I did downvote, because this question was looking really obvious to me. I mean, by definition function in $C^{\infty}_c$ are bounded and zero outside a compact set. This is enough to see they are in $L^p(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$. Then $f$ is supported in a compact set $K$ and $|f|$ attains a maximum $C$ in this $K$. Thus

$$\int_{\Omega} |f|^p dx = \int_K |f|^p dx \le \int_K C^p dx = \text{Vol}(K) C^p.$$

Thus $f\in L^p$ for all $p$. Indeed $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p$ for all $1\le p <\infty$.

Comment: But density won't hold for $p=\infty$?

Comment: it does not. @0xbadf00d

Comment: Does it hold under suitable assumptions on $\Omega$?

Comment: No. for example if $g = \chi_B$ is the characteristic function of a ball $B$ in $\Omega$, there is no $f\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ so that $\|  f- g\|_\infty < \frac 13$.

Comment: For a bounded open set $\Omega$, how do you exactly show that $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$ for $p \in [1,\infty)$? Could you briefly explain?

Answer (score 0):

Well yeah it has compact support, hence outside of a compact set $K$ is zero. It's continuos on a bounded, closed set hence its integral must be smaller than $M\cdot m(K)$, where $M$ is the maximum of the function on $K$ and $m$ is the lebesgue measure

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that  $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ is the space of $C^\infty$ with compact support contained in $\Omega$. If that's the case, then you don't care whether or not $\Omega$ has finite measure, since

$$
\int_\Omega |u|^pdx\leq |spt(u)|\cdot\max |u|^p<\infty.
$$

where $spt(u)$ is the *support* of $u$, that is defined as

$$
spt(u)=\overline{\{x\in \Omega : u(x)\neq 0\}}.
$$

Since the support is compact, it is boudned, so $|spt(u)| < \infty$.

Comment: Sorry, see the edit.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure this is the fastest and most elegant solution, but this fact is rather a standard fact from distribution theory.

$\textbf{First case}:$ If $\Omega$ is bounded than it is obvious (as you wrote), since set has finite Lebesgue measure.

$\textbf{Second case}:$ Set $\Omega$ is open and unbounded. This is not trivial fact (but a good excercise) to show that in $R^d$ every open set can be represented as a countable union of open balls - therefore it is true for $\Omega$. Therefore it can be shown that it is possible to build an increasing sequence of compact sets $\{K_n\}, \, K_i\subset \Omega$
$$
 K_1 \subset K_2 \dots \subset K_n\dots, \, \bigcup_i K_i = \Omega.
$$
Having such sequence it is possible to build $L^p$ approximations of any function $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ by setting $f_n(x) = f(x)\cdot I_{K_n}(x)$. By the Lebesgue Theorem for limits of function sequences, this $\{f_n(x)\}$ will be indeed an approximation in $L^p$ - norm (also as an exercise to show it).
The technical point then is to choose the $K_i$ such that the support of $f_n(x)$ will be $\delta$-inside the $\Omega$ (it is not difficult to do, knowing that $\Omega$ is a countable union of open balls). The last we do - take some function $\phi\in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ from the ``delta-sequence''  with support in the $\delta/2$-ball in $R^d$. Taking a convolution $\phi*f_n$ will give you a function from $C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$
with desired accuracy in $L^p$ norm.

p.s. Sorry that I didn't wrote what is delta-sequence, but it is rather standard object from distribution theory, same as idea of smoothing through convolution.

Comment: I think that your answer is unresonably complicated. It is just standard exercise using only two facts: 1) continous function on compact set attains maximum 2) compact sets have finiet Lebesgue measure. Your approach is like shooting to a sparrow with a cannonball. It may scare off unexpirienced users.

Comment: it is not a method, I didn't see that question is that simple. I thought it was about dense embedding of $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega) \rightarrow L^p(\Omega)$. "May scare unexperienced users" -- just no comments.