# Density of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ for a bounded open set $\Omega$ - any detailed proof?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, approximation, smooth-functions

Let $\Omega$ be an open, bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (NOT necesasrily with smooth boundary).

Now, let $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ be the space of smooth functions on $\Omega$ with compact support.

Then

> How to prove that $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ dense in $L^p(\Omega)$ for each $p \in [1,\infty)$?

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1857441/c-c-infty-omega-subseteq-lp-omega-for-any-open-omega) has almost the same question and answer, but no details of proof.

Could anyone please provide some details (or at least sketch of) how to do the approximation correctly?

Comment: Perhaps use convolution with a mollifier to approximate L^p by C_c^$\infty$

Comment: @fGDu94 That is the point. How can I be sure that convolution with a mollfier belongs to $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$?

Comment: Use a mollifier from $C_c^{\infty}$

Comment: Look up Folland’s analysis book. This is one if the last theorems in the section on convolutions.

Comment: Or if you know $C_c$ is dense, then you can apply Stone-Weierstrass to get a polynomial which uniformly approximates it. Then, multiply by a smooth bump function to get something with compact support. Lastly, bounded open set is not important.

Comment: @peek-a-boo The section on convolutions mostly deal with whole $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you are talking about the $C^\infty$ Urysohn lemma, I don't think that lemma is that much relevant to this question.

Comment: understand what happens in $\Bbb{R}^n$; a minor rewording gives you the result for all open $\Omega$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156444/why-c-0-infty-is-dense-in-lp This seems to contain all the details.